# Добавление рекламы admob 22.1.0

Tags: libgdx

Как добавить rewarded video (видео) рекламу в мое приложение Libgdx на android ?
В интернете примеры кода написаны под старые версии adMob, мне же нужно под последнюю текущую версию 22.0.1.

---

Вот эта замечательная статья помогла мне - https://libgdx.com/wiki/third-party/admob-in-libgdx#code.
Здесь пример как добавить видео рекламу - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KfmRZapbkc.
А так же вот здесь есть пособие для старта - https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=ru.